# Cannot delete row from table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to delete a row from the table,

My code :

```
var strUsername = GridMain.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim();
Users selectedUser = _db.Users.First(usr => usr.UserName == strUsername);

_db.DeleteObject(selectedUser);
_db.SaveChanges();

LoadGrid(PresentationMode.Users);
```

My code is working properly

But for only one row of database, an error occurs on `SaveChanges()`

Error Message :

> An error occurred while updating the entries. See the InnerException
>   for details

Row which the error occurs on that :

[image]

Inner Exception:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   "FK_UserReport_Users". The conflict occurred in database
>   "Reporter", table "dbo.UsersReports", column 'UserName'.

Comment: And what is the InnerException?

Comment: And what does the `.InnerExecption` say? That would be extremely useful to know ......

Comment: Also, this looks like EF, not Linq2SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Row is available/referenced in UserReport table. So you can't delete it unless you have enabled cascaded delete option. or else delete the row in UserReport and try delete again.

Answer (score 1):

Reference is existed in UserReport Table.so you can't delete parent table values..first u remove parent child relationship or use cascaded delete option